# R plot list of list with ggplot2

Tags: r, list, plot, ggplot2, dataframe

I have the following dataset:

*resultsDataFrame* -> data.frame containing multiple lists

```
names(resultsDataFrame)
[1] "ModelType" "Residuals"

typeof(resultsDataFrame$Residuals)
[1] "list"

typeof(resultsDataFrame$ModelType)
[1] "list"

head(resultsDataFrame$ModelType)
[[1]]
[1] "bayesglm"

[[2]]
[1] "glm"

[[3]]
[1] "kernelpls"

[[4]]
[1] "knn"

[[5]]
[1] "lars"

[[6]]
[1] "lm"
```

*ModelType* -> a list with a single string at each position

*Residuals* -> a list of vectors

What I want to do is to plot each "Residuals" list entry (which is a vector), with the corresponding "ModelType" label. So that I'll have as many plots as *resultsDataFrame* rows.

I've been trying things like

```
g <- ggplot(resultsDataFrame, aes(seq(1:length(Residuals),unlist(Residuals))))
print(g + geom_point())

qplot(unlist(Residuals), data = resultsDataFrame, facets = ~ ModelType)
```

But no luck

Thank you in advance

Comment: If `resultsDataFrame` really is a data frame, and some columns really are lists, then I wouldn't expect anything in R to handle a data structure like that in a predictable way.

Comment: Thank you, I ended up using llply to extract the data into separate ggplots!